# Install Versions higher than 14.04.2 on Lenovo Yoga 3 11

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, lenovo, crash

Trying to boot any kernel version 4 freezes on boot.
No installation possible, because even that boot freezes.
If I install the wily kernel on my 14.04 my system won't boot anymore.
If I try to install Ubuntu 14.04.5 or any higher version, it freezes while boot.

The kernel simply crashes. Randomly.

Did anyone ever manage to install any version using kernel 4.x.x on a Lenovo yoga 3 11 (not pro) ?

Comment: Have you tried 16.10? Also, have you tried booting it in legacy mode instead of UEFI?

Comment: Update BIOS/UEFI. Try disabling Secure Boot and Fast Boot. As a last resource you may try the suggestion above. Also prefer 16.04.1 or 16.10 for that hardware.

Comment: I tried installing 16.04, 16.10, the most recent daily  build, 14.04.5. I also installed different kernels on my existing 14.04. It all led to the same freeze on boot. Booting 14.04.2 was no problem. I messed around with BIOS settings. Maybe an update there would change something.